# iPhone how to fetch data asynchronously from a web service with API call limit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, concurrency, afnetworking

I'm pulling data from a web service with an API call limit of 125 per hour. My initial sync of the user's data will use a method similar to the one below. **I'm having trouble understanding the correctness of concurrency implications of the code below.**

I'm adding a series of AFHTTPRequestOperation over to a serial NSOPerationsQueue (max concurrent count = 1). The resulting calls return asynchronously and cause the method to process the data dictionary. Because of the API call limit, I know that at some point my code will fail and start to return error dictionaries instead.

**Can I expect the following code to return full data dictionaries sequentially, or due to asynchronous nature of callbacks, can some of them complete before earlier requests?**

Because I'm trying to do initial sync, I want to make sure that once the code fails due to API call limit, I have no "holes" in my data up until the failure point.

```
-(void)addRequestWithString:(NSString*)requestString
{


    // 1: Create a NSURL and a NSURLRequest to points to the web service providing data. Add Oauth1 information to the request, including any extra parameters that are not in scope of Oauth1 protocol

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [ self.auth authorizeRequest:request withExtraParams:self.extraAuthParameters];



    // 2: Use AFHTTPRequestOperation class, alloc and init it with the request.
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *datasource_download_operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    // 3: Give the user feedback, while downloading the data source by enabling network activity indicator.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

    // 4: By using setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:, you can add two blocks: one for the case where the operation finishes successfully, and one for the case where it fails.
    [datasource_download_operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {



        NSDictionary* dictonary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)responseObject
                                                                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];


        [self processResponseDictionary:dictonary];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){

        // 8: In case you are not successful, you display a message to notify the user.
        // Connection error message
        DLog(@"API fetch error: %@", error);

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    }];

    // 9: Finally, add ìdatasource_download_operationî to ìdownloadQueueî of PendingOperations.
    [[self syncQueue] addOperation:datasource_download_operation];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will continue the operations even after they start failing.

If you need the operations to go one at a time, but stop once the failure block is hit, enqueue a new request in the completion block of the prior request.

(This code is from an answer to [AFNetworking Synchronous Operation in NSOperationQueue on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11325473/1445366); I didn't write it.)

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [operations reverseObjectEnumerator];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *currentOperation = nil;
AFHTTPRequestOperation *nextOperation = [enumerator nextObject]; 
while (nextOperation != nil && (currentOperation = [enumerator nextObject])) {
  currentOperation.completionBlock = ^{
    [client enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:nextOperation];
  }
  nextOperation = currentOperation;
}
[client enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:currentOperation];
```

If the failure block is hit, the following operations will never be enqueued.