# Swift Completion Block

Tags: swift, closures, completion-block

I want to achieve the following :

1. In classB, to reload my database after adding 1 object. `reloadDatabase()` is called within the completionBlock.
2. In classB, `reloadDatabase()` will call `getObjects()` in `classA` to get the most updated list of database objects and pass to `objectList` in classB

Question: How do i ensure that whenever i call `getObjectList()` in classB, i will always get the most updated list? From my understanding, my `objectList` might not be update in `reloadDatabase() block`.  I could be calling `getObjectList()` when `reloadDatabase()` haven't reach the completion block yet (objectList is still the old objectList).

I am pretty new to closures and blocks. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

```
    class classA: NSObject { 
      func addThisObject(object: RLMObject, completionBlock: () -> ())){

        ...
        completionBlock()
      } 


      func getObjects (completionBlock: ((list: [RLMObject]) -> ())){

        var recordList = [RLMObject]()
        ...
        completionBlock(list: recordList)
      }
    }


    class classB: NSObject { 

      var objectList = [RLMObject]()

      func addObject (object: RLMObject) {

        classA().addThisObject(object, completionBlock: {() -> () in
          self.reloadDatabase()
        }) 

      }

     func reloadDatabase() {

       classA().getObjects{(list) -> () in 
         self.objectList = list 
       }
    }

     func getObjectList() -> [RLMObject] {
       return objectList 
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your snippets it seems to me there is no asynchronous calls, so you won't be able to call `getObjectList()` before `reloadDatabase()` block. Closures are not asynchronous if you don't use them with something that is (e.g. GCD).

If you have asynchronous calls, but they are not in the snippets, then `getObjectList()` can be called while `reloadDatabase()` is being executed. Then you have few options:

- Remove asynchronous calls
- Use [serial queue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) for your methods
- Add boolean variable `updateInProgress` and check it in `getObjectList()` - [how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824394/waiting-for-condition-to-continue)
- Ignore the fact that data may be outdated - it is correctness vs speed trade.
- Let your database inform its clients that something changed

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you don't say whether you'll be calling any of these functions from different threads. So when you call addObject() in classB, execution wouldn't even continue until the database has been reloaded and objectList was updated.

Using closures and blocks does not automatically imply that code will be executed on a different context.