# DNS Query with COCOA (for A, CNAME, MX, etc) records?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, dns

I need to perform some DNS request from within a COCOA / Objective-C App (OSX).  Is there any framework (like Ruby Resolv) that i could use for this? I **don't** want to use shell/cli and parse the result.

I need to query the following record types:

- SOA
- NS
- A
- CNAME
- MX

Any help / pointers much appreciated!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330816/objective-c-dns-txt-record (which is for a TXT record, but can be modified for other queries).

Comment: great, thats what i was looking for!