# Objective-C: DNS SOA Record

Tags: ios, objective-c, dns, soa

What is the best way to get SOA record from the specific DNS server? I have an array of servers and need to ask randomly one of them about SOA record of some host.

I need this to be working on iOS and be approved by apple.

PS This is not quite what I need since I cannot specify suctom DNS IP here - [Objective-C: DNS TXT Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330816/objective-c-dns-txt-record)

---

UPDATE:

Found this solution: http://www.software7.com/blog/programmatically-query-specific-dns-servers-on-ios/
It is exactly what I need except lib resolv doesn't compiled for arm64 :(

---

UPDATE 2:
Previous link works; I just forgot to link a library. Will post this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution: http://www.software7.com/blog/programmatically-query-specific-dns-servers-on-ios/ It is exactly what I need. I've reworked a little it for my specific proposes, but it fits in general

Answer (score 0):

The way to get a `SOA` record from a DNS server is to send the server a query asking for it. If there is no standard library on iOS with the ability to do that, you should be able to include a third-party one. I like this one: https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/ldns/