# How to wait past dispatch_async before proceeding?

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have a series of dispatch_async that I am performing and I would like to only update the UI when they are all done.  Problem is the method within dispatch_async calls something in a separate thread so it returns before the data is fully loaded and dispatch_group_notify is called before everything is loaded.

So I introduce a infinite loop to make it wait until a flag is set.
Is this the best way? See code below.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

for (...) {
  dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    __block BOOL dataLoaded = NO;

    [thirdPartyCodeCallWithCompletion:^{
       dataLoaded = YES;
    }];

    // prevent infinite loop
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), 
    queue, ^{
          dataLoaded = YES;
    });

    // infinite loop to wait until data is loaded
    while (1) {
       if (dataLoaded) break;
    }
  }

  dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //update UI
  });
}
```

Comment: Infinite loops are never the best way :) Try a dispatch_semaphore_t instead; see [How do I wait for an asynchronously dispatched block to finish?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326350/how-do-i-wait-for-an-asynchronously-dispatched-block-to-finish/4326754#4326754)

Answer (score 9):

You're already aware of dispatch groups. Why not just use `dispatch_group_wait()`, which includes support for a timeout? You can use `dispatch_group_enter()` and `dispatch_group_leave()` rather than `dispatch_group_async()` to make the group not done until the internal block for the third-party call with completion is finished.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

for (...) {
  dispatch_group_enter(group);
  dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    [thirdPartyCodeCallWithCompletion:^{
       dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];
  }
}

dispatch_group_wait(group, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSECS_PER_SEC));
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  //update UI
});
```

---

The use of `dispatch_group_wait()` does make this code synchronous, which is bad if run on the main thread. Depending on what exactly is supposed to happen if it times out, you could use `dispatch_group_notify()` as you were and use `dispatch_after()` to just updates the UI rather than trying to pretend the block completed.

---

Update: I tweaked my code to make sure that "update UI" happens on the main queue, just in case this code isn't already on the main thread.

By the way, I only used `dispatch_async()` for the block which calls `thirdPartyCodeCallWithCompletion:` because your original used `dispatch_group_async()` and I wasn't sure that the hypothetical method was asynchronous. Most APIs which take a completion block are asynchronous, though. If that one is, then you can just invoke it directly.

Comment: Hi Ken, I use your proposed method but the code is stuck - update UI is never called.  I don't have this issue with the semaphore approach.

Comment: I messed up the timeout parameter to `dispatch_group_wait()`. I was passing a delta but it needs an absolute time. I have fixed the code.

Answer (score 8):

Another method is to use [semaphore](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/synchronization/synchronization.html) and the [dispatch_semaphore_wait](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_semaphore_wait):

```
// Create your semaphore, 0 is specifying the initial pool size
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    @autoreleasepool {

    // Your code goes here

    }
   // Release the resource and signal the semaphore
   dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
 });

// Wait for the above block execution, AKA Waits for (decrements) a semaphore.
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
// After this line you can now safely assert anything you want regarding the async operation since it is done.
```

Comment: This causes program hanging forever if switched to another thread. This is almost like `dispatch_sync`

Comment: Not sure how your code looks like but it really depends how you use it, after all, it's a snip code