# How to prevent dispatch group to not crash?

Tags: objective-c, macos, grand-central-dispatch

I am using the below code to wait for async tasks to be completed. It works a couple of times and crashes. The `updateFromTable` always invokes `callback()` so that the group calls are balanced, but it still crashes.

```
- (void)updateFromTable:(Table *)table env:(Env *)env callback:(void (^)(void))callback {
    [someasync usingBlock:^{
        callback()
    }];
}

- (NSString * _Nullable)process {
    JSL * __weak weakSelf = self;
    NSString __block *ret = nil;
    dispatch_group_enter(_dispatchGroup);
    dispatch_async(_repQueue, ^{
        JSL *this = weakSelf;
        [this updateFromTable:[this->_env table] env:this->_env callback:^{
            ret = [some op .. ];
            dispatch_group_leave(this->_dispatchGroup);
        }];
    });
    dispatch_group_wait(_dispatchGroup, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC));
    info(@"%@", @"done");
    return ret;
}
```

Any idea why it crashes randomly and how to fix this? Basically, what I am trying to achieve is invoke couple of async tasks, wait for all of them to complete and then proceed with the rest.

---

Referring: [How to wait past dispatch_async before proceeding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616983/how-to-wait-past-dispatch-async-before-proceeding/23618844#23618844)

Comment: It would be better if you didn't attempt to convert an async call into a synchronous call. Change `process` to take a completion handler instead of directly returning a value.

Comment: This is an interactive command line app, so the user waits for the result.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you should properly work with async calls.

Comment: In synchronous mode, the main function takes a string calls process, which executes a bunch of function and returns. If process is async, it returns and result is not available to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot dereference ivars with `->` if `this` is `nil`. So, the typical solution is to create strong reference that can’t be deallocated while the closure runs, and `return` if it’s `nil`:

```
- (NSString * _Nullable)process {
    typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
    [self asynchronousMethodWithCompletion:^{
        typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (!strongSelf) { return; }

        // can now safely use `strongSelf` here
    });

    ...
}
```

This is “`weakSelf`-`strongSelf` dance”. You use it in situations where you need to make sure that `self` isn’t `nil` when you use it, e.g. dereferencing ivars (`strongSelf->ivar`) .

Thus:

```
- (NSString * _Nullable)process {
    typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
    NSString __block *ret = nil;
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    dispatch_async(_repQueue, ^{
        typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (!strongSelf) { return; }

        [strongSelf updateFromTable:[strongSelf->_env table] env:strongSelf->_env callback:^{
            ret = [some op .. ];
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }];
    });
    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    info(@"%@", @"done");
    return ret;
}
```

A few other observations:

- The dispatch group should be a local variable of the method rather than an ivar. There’s no need for anything else in your code referencing this `group`.
- Make sure that your `dispatch_group_leave` calls don’t exceed the number of `dispatch_group_enter` calls (i.e. that this completion handler block isn’t called multiple times).
- I’d suggest waiting for `DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER` (assuming you want it to really wait for it to finish).
- Also, if these are properties (which I’m guessing they are on the basis of the underscores), then using `self.env` rather than `self->_env` is safer, as it won’t crash if `self` is `nil`, but rather will just return `nil`.

I must confess that this still doesn’t look right (e.g. if `updateFromTable` is asynchronous already, why bother dispatching this asynchronously to `_repQueue`; if it is synchronous, then again, why dispatch this asynchronously only to wait for it). But it’s impossible to comment further without seeing the `updateFromTable` implementation.

---

Or, better, make the method asynchronous:

```
- (void)processWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSString *))callback {
    typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(_repQueue, ^{
        typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (!strongSelf) { return; }

        [strongSelf updateFromTable:[strongSelf->_env table] env:strongSelf->_env callback:^{
            NSString *ret = [some op .. ];
            callback(ret);
        }];
    });
}
```

Comment: I checked the `this` var, and it is not nil.

Comment: Looks like the crash due to async dispatch is fixed by using local dispatch group var and checking callback count.