# NSURLSession in a separate class cannot pass data to the ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm learning the NSURLSession class and I wanted to create a separate class in my project with all the methods I use to retrieve data from a web service.

This is the header file, `tclass.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface tclass : NSObject

- (void)returnIP;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *IP ;

@end
```

This is the implementation file, `tclass.m`

```
#import "tclass.h"

@implementation tclass

- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  return self;
}

- (void)returnIP {
  NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
  [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://icanhazip.com/"]
    completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
        NSURLResponse *response,
        NSError *error) {
      [self setIP:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]]];
    }] resume];
}


@end
```

In my ViewController class, I firstly use the `returnIP` method to retrieve the data and to store it in a property then I update the UI, all of this using `dispatch_async`.

```
- (IBAction)butact:(id)sender {
  tclass *t = [[tclass alloc]init];

  [_round setHidden:NO];
  [_round startAnimating];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
      [t returnIP];
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_round stopAnimating];
        [_round setHidden:NO];
        [_lab setText:[t IP]];
        });
      });

}
```

My problem is that the IP property is not populated, and the UI update does not appear to be done even though I'm using the main queue to do it.

How can I accomplish this process?

Is my approach completely wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use completion block parameter pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26174930/1271826

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Rob who commented my post I implemented a solution based on blocks.

Here's the updated class header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface tclass : NSObject

- (void)returnIP:(void (^)(NSString *ip))completionHandler;

@end
```

and the implementation

```
#import "tclass.h"

@implementation tclass

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

- (void)returnIP:(void (^)(NSString *ip))completionHandler {

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://icanhazip.com/"]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {
                if(completionHandler) {
                    completionHandler([NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]]);
                }
            }] resume];
}

@end
```

The mechanism used to call this method is a bit changed:

```
- (IBAction)butact:(id)sender {
    tclass *t = [[tclass alloc]init];

    [_round setHidden:NO];
    [_round startAnimating];

    [t returnIP:^(NSString *ip) {
        NSLog(@"%@", ip);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [_round stopAnimating];
            [_round setHidden:YES];
            [_lab setText:ip];
        });
    }];

}
```

Comment: It would be better to include a way to pass an error back (if one should occur) in your block as well. You could either change the return type to id, and check whether it's a string or an NSError object, or have the completion handler return a string and an error object (one of which would be nil in any single return).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm still learning how to manage errors in Obj-C and returning both the string and the error object seems to be the best choice.