# UIView.animateWithDuration not executing with semaphore

Tags: animation, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I'm attempting to write a function that will flash a view's background color to white then back to it's original color. What I have is:

```
func flashView(view: UIView) {
    var sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    var color = view.backgroundColor
    println("Animating")
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor() }) {
        (success: Bool) in
        println("First block completion")
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { view.backgroundColor = color }) {
            (success: Bool) in
            println("Nested block completion")
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)
        }
    }
    println("Waiting")
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    println("Returning")
}
```

Now, what I'm experiencing is that the `Animating` message will display followed by the `Waiting`. The first `animateWithDuration` block never gets executed (and needless to say the nested one does not either. However, according to Apple's own [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW3) the `UIView.animateWithDuration` occurs on a separate thread. So, my understanding, is that the semaphore should wait, the `animateWithDuration` should complete on a separate thread, and the function should return (after waiting on the semaphore that's signaled in the nested closure). What am I misunderstanding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Animation block executes in main thread, and your dispatch_semaphore_wait blocks main thread.
So animation block never executes.

This is one solution.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        println("Returning")
    })
```

other solutions are here:
[How do I wait for an asynchronously dispatched block to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326350/how-do-i-wait-for-an-asynchronously-dispatched-block-to-finish)

Comment: Apple's documentation (from the link in the original question) explicitly says new threads are spun up to complete the animation:

`When this code executes, the specified animations are started immediately on another thread so as to avoid blocking the current thread or your application’s main thread.`

Comment: I think Apple says that animation blocks execute asynchronously not to prevent main thread. This does not mean that animations execute in sub thread. You can check the thread in which a code executes by "NSThread.isMainThread()".