# Objective-C Block: return __block variable from block inside

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

OK, here is the code.

```
NSObject* (^executableBlock)(void) = ^NSObject*() {
    __block NSObject *refObj = nil;

    [Utility performAction:^() {
         if (conditionA)
              refObj = fooA;
         else
              refObj = fooB;
    };

    return refObj;
};

NSObject *result = executableBlock();   // result is nil
```

After executing the executableBlock, the result is nil and performAction block didn't be executed immediately and returned my expected value.

I know performAction block is executed within another thread and using the shared nil pointer refObj. Refer to [Working with Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html).

Here is my through, if I use GCD to call the performAction block and wait for its finish, how to rewrite it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using semaphore, you can wait until a block is done.
But completion-block may be suitable in your case, i think.

```
NSObject* (^executableBlock)(void) = ^NSObject*() {
    __block NSObject *refObj = nil;

    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [self performAction:^() {
        if (conditionA)
            refObj = fooA;
        else
            refObj = fooB;

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    return refObj;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I just found an answer after searching keywords **dispatch_semaphore_create**. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4326754/1677041

Answer (score 0):

I would considering the following re-structure:

```
    __block NSObject * result;
    void (^executableBlock)(NSObject *) =  ^void (NSObject * obj)
    {
        [self performAnActionWithBlock:^(BOOL success)
        {
            if (success) {
                result = obj;
                NSLog(@"results: %@", result);
            }else{
               result = nil;
            }

        }];
    };
    executableBlock(@"Hello");


//where:
-(void)performAnActionWithBlock:(void(^)(BOOL))block{
    block(YES);
}
```

You should then be able to call `result` from elsewhere

Comment: I don't think so, this'll cause unexpected behavior. I think you just want to share an obj pointer among blocks/threads. If the performAnActionWithBlock is async and didn't be invoked in background thread before I used obj pointer in main thread, so the result may be null.

Comment: The same with @user3087154 , I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
void (^executableBlock)(NSObject*) = ^(NSObject *arg) {

[Utility performAction:^(NSObject *arg) {
     if (conditionA)
          arg = fooA;
     else
          arg = fooB;
}];
```

};

__block NSObject *result = nil;

executableBlock(result);   // result will be changed in block

Comment: Please add more detail about your answer and why this answer works.