# Is there a way to wait for a query to be finished in Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm querying in an iOS app in a Viewcontroller with a TableView. I want to be guaranteed my query has returned before I want to proceed to load the TableView. Is there a way to guarantee the query has finished?

Comment: See [How do I wait for an asynchronously dispatched block to finish?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326350/how-do-i-wait-for-an-asynchronously-dispatched-block-to-finish). Semaphores are what you're looking for here.

Comment: Also see Frank's [authoritative discussion of async and AngularFire](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049342/impossible-to-access-array-with-angular-and-firebase).