# Does Firebase signInWithEmail function run in main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

when I run the following code:

---

```
[[FIRAuth auth] signInWithEmail:@"myemail@mydomain.com"
                           password:@"hdfjhfjhdbf"
                         completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {

                             NSLog(@"I am in Block");
                         }];
NSLog(@"I am here");
```

---

my output is : 
I am here
I am in Block
it means that the FIRAuth block runs in another thread other than main thread.
I add an extra line to the code (while infinite loop)

---

```
[[FIRAuth auth] signInWithEmail:@"myemail@mydomain.com"
                           password:@"hdfjhfjhdbf"
                         completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {

                             NSLog(@"I am in Block");
                         }];
NSLog(@"I am here");
while (YES) {};
```

---

my output is : 
I am here

the question: if the FIRAuth block runs in another thread it should print "I am in block" no matter we have infinite loop in main thread. how could it be possible?does the FIRAuth block runs by less priority in same main thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually in Firebase we:

- run the operations that interact with network and disk in a separate thread
- surface the callbacks back on the main thread, so that your code can interact with the UI

I didn't verify for this specific case, but expect it to work the same. And that means that your infinite loop is preventing the completion block from being executed.

If you want to wait for a result, use semaphores as describes here: [How do I wait for an asynchronously dispatched block to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326350/how-do-i-wait-for-an-asynchronously-dispatched-block-to-finish)

Comment: Does FIRAuth have a property that return "true" when the block is completed? I had experience with Dynamodb amazon, their functions have "completed" boolean property

Comment: It has a property `currentUser`, which is documented as "Synchronously gets the cached current user, or null if there is none." The documentation is your friend here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_auth#instance-method-summary

Comment: but I am still not completely convinced how FIRAuth threats the threads. the following example show that infinite loop does not block other threads executing. Are you aware of any dispatch setting that behaves like FIRAuth in which infinite loop blocks other queues execution?  dispatch_queue_t queue=dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        while (TRUE){NSLog(@"I'm in Block 1"); usleep(200);}
    });
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
         while (TRUE){NSLog(@"I'm in Block 2"); usleep(200);}
    });
    while (TRUE){};